# TypeScript - Initialize enum-variable with its value

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have declared an own enum type.

```
export enum MyEnum {
    FIRSTENTRY = 'B',
    SECONDENTRY = 'F',
    ...
}
```

I also get some data from a service.

```
res:[{ID: 1, description: "someText", MyEnumType: "F", ...}, {...}, ...]
```

I want to do something like that:

```
let test:MyEnumType = res[0].MyEnumType;

test === MyEnum.SECONDENTRY (=> true)
```

Is there in Angular/TypeScript any way without a switch/case or other manually checking for the value? Would be very helpfull and interesting to know.

Comment: You're code seems to be fine, I just assume you need to replace test: MyEnumType with test: MyEnum, and res equals the array not colon then it should be fine